# Loop through an ASP.Net table

Tags: javascript, asp.net, loops, client-side

I have a table which is created dynamically through C#; now I have a simple client side checkbox which will loop through the table each time it's clicked. I think I can handle looping through the table, currently though I'm just having issues of trying to loop through the table using JavaScript.

So far I have a checkbox:

Then I have my function which will loop through the table

```
<script>
    function LoopThroughTable() {
        var chkState = document.getElementById("chkSelectAll");
        alert(document.getElementById("fileTablePersonal").rows.length);

        if (chkState.checked) {
            alert("Loop through table");
        } else {
            alert("Loop through table again");
        }
     }
</script>
```

My main issue at the minute is that I can't alert the number or rows or columns using JavaScript, I'm using rows.length but that doesn't seem to work

Any help would be awesome

Edit: My table is created using Asp.Net

Comment: how are u calling LoopThroughTable? rows.length works fine for me...http://jsfiddle.net/mxu9W/

Comment: It's an Asp.Net table, not a normal html table

Comment: but finally its rendered as html table only.Try to view source from browser

Comment: how are u calling the above client side function??

Comment: Awesome, that was the problem, although I had the table ID as fileTablePersonal; when rendered it was ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_fileTablePersonal... It's working now, thanks for the help!

Comment: ohh so u where usng a master page??

Comment: Nope, it was being created in my files.aspx page where my JavaScript code is

Comment: if u are not using a master page how come u are using a content place holder?

Comment: No idea; it'#s just what gets rendered to the source code, my id is just fileTablePersonal, unless you meant using a master page, I am using a master page, but my code/table is in the files.aspx page, master page is just used for the layout of the web site

Comment: posted an answer which shows your problem and the actual solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using master page, you cannot access elements using their actual ids but their `ClientId`

Suppose you have a asp.net  table as is your case

```
<asp:Table ID="tblTable" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

In your page simply declare the below script

```
<script>
    var tblTable = '<%=tblTable.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

Now you can access your table using the keyword tblTable like as below

```
alert(document.getElementById(tblTable).rows.length);
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

You have to use easyui jquery might be.. and datagrid js

```
 $('#fileTablePersonal').datagrid('getRows').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **ClientIdMode = "static"** in server control, if you are  not using it inside any repeter/list view type data controler.

```
<asp:Table ID="fileTablePersonal" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static">
    <asp:TableRow>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

alert(document.getElementById("fileTablePersonal").rows.length);
```